# Missing API key for Google Cloud

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

I'm attempting to use [Google's Natural Language API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php) for PHP, and having followed the instructions, I'm getting an error in the application I've written:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: {
>   "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The request is missing a valid API
>   key.", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }

I've downloaded the account key file, run the export, but I get the 403 error.

I've created a symbolic link to the file in the project folder, run the export, but I get the 403 error.

I placed the export in the ".bash_profile" file, exited the terminal session, but I get the 403 error.

> Provide authentication credentials to your application code by setting
>   the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. Replace
>   [PATH] with the file path of the JSON file that contains your service
>   account key, and [FILE_NAME] with the filename. **This variable only
>   applies to your current shell session, so if you open a new session,
>   set the variable again**.

When I ran: `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` the export isn't there, so I ran it again, but I get the 403 error.

I followed the documentation to the letter, and I've gone through it three times, and each time I get the same 403 error.

I see no instructions asking me to store a string value for the API key in the application, but I've found a number of people recommending that, but not provide an example of how or where.

So, some advice would be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply do not use an export; while your `~/.bashrc` is not apache's `.bashrc`.

but add the path to the file directly into the PHP code; eg. into a `config.php`.

**or** use `putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/var/www/[FILE_NAME].json');`

while preventing HTTP access to that file with `.htaccess`.

**or** one can even setup with `.htaccess`, alike

```
SetEnv GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS "/var/www/[FILE_NAME].json"
```

Comment: Hi Martin, the ".htaccess" did nothing, but the "config.php" did, but it's another error: "Fatal error: Uncaught DomainException: Unable to read the credential file specified by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: file path/name.json does not exist in /path/vendor/google/auth/src/CredentialsLoader.php:73" What's strange is that I get the same error with a relative path to the SymLink and an absolute path to the actual file.

Comment: @WayneSmallman the `.htaccess` file might be at the wrong location; and when referencing the file directly, that path should be either absolute from the top `/` or relative to the `CredentialsLoader.php` or possibly relative the location of the script which accesses it. symlinks often only work when enabling them with `Options +FollowSymLinks` . also when it's located completely outside of the web-root, this often will not work due to "open basedir" restriction.

Comment: The ".htaccess" is correct; the application is using it. Also, in there at the top is: `Options +FollowSymlinks`. I tried the instruction again with the absolute path from root but it's still not recognizing it. I tried the same path in "config.php" and that gave me me the original error.

Comment: I found a space in the API key file name that should have been a "-", and it's now working. Martin, thank you.

Comment: @WayneSmallman Linux needs needs spaces in paths escaped with a backslash.